# Dynamically created div behavior on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I went through many post from **SO** but not able to relate with my scenario.

I have this code on button click. by which User can create as many div on runtime as he wants to on UI.

```
$('#adddiv').click(function () {
    debugger;
    $('#main').append('<div class="ara-dynamic-div">
          <div class="box box-solid bg-light-blue-gradient">
          </Div></div>');
});
```

code to get buttonclick event from that div

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
    showMakeAndHold(this);
});


function showMakeAndHold(obj) {
    alert(obj);
    $('.ara-dynamic-div').fadeOut();
}
```

> Now the problem is that I have to create multiple dynamic div. and each div will have button to close itself. When I call this function it will close all created div's instead of the one which button is clicked.

I am not able to find the proper div by which request for close come. I am new to DOM and JQuery. not able to relate the things

[image]

Comment: Without looking any further, IDs are UNIQUE - your code adds the same div and button ID every time a new DIV is created - therefore delete one will delete them all if you're targeting div ID - also same button ID will fire when `$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {` fires

Comment: @DarrenSweeney hey but how to overcome from that. when user create 10 div dynamically. then how will i differ each one of them and then able to close it.

Comment: Have a look at `closest()` or `parent()` (if always same structure) in jquery - you give the button and outer div a CLASS, not ID, then when that button class is clicked you look for closest div with new div class and remove it

Comment: With same div ID it is not possible.Make class same but keep IDS dfferent .Create dynamic remove button with every new created div and make a onclick **function removeElement("myDiv2")** this button is for myDiv2 .Its changes with every div as all divs have uniqie ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you're using multiple divs you shouldn't give the close button an ID, but a class instead (let's say, `.close`)

Next you can use event delegation to find the correct element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ara-dynamic-div .close', function( event ) {
    $(this).closest('.ara-dynamic-div').fadeOut();
} )
```

The delegator handles all click events in any `.ara-dynamic-div .close` button, catching them all and allowing you to use `$(this).closest(...)` to get to the parent container.

Edit: Corrected a mistake

Comment: That will fade only the button out - use something like this `$(this).closest('.ara-dynamic-div').hide();`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Yes I just realized that a moment after posting, don't know what I was thinking ;) Edited it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `.closest()` function.

```
function showMakeAndHold(obj) {
    alert(obj);
    $(obj).closest('.ara-dynamic-div').fadeOut();
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xry782s/)

Comment: never use alert for debuggging

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
    showMakeAndHold(this);
});
```

by this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
    $(".ara-dynamic-div").not($(this).parents(".ara-dynamic-div")).fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kps4hea0/)

What the code does is that it remove all other `.ara-dynamic-div` except the one for which the button was clicked.